# Is there any chance to set soft keyboard as default programatically?

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to use custom keyboard for my application, but I don't want to force the user to go into setting page to set my keyboard as the default keyboard. 
What do I need to do to force my keyboard in my application?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any chance to set soft keyboard as default programatically?

Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @user1865354: The number of entries in the Settings app for available input methods will vary by device, Android version, and what third-party input methods a user has already installed.

Comment: ok.. otherwise in settings screen there is 4 keyboards right.. i,e AOSP,Sample Soft keyboard, Japanese, etc.. instead of customized one i am trying to use Sample Soft Keyboard.. is there chance to set it as default through program..

Comment: @user1865354: "is there chance to set it as default through program" -- fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons.